# Node.js app works locally but heroku says missing module

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I made a simple chat application using Node.JS and Socket.IO, everything works fine locally, but when I push it to heroku it gives me an application error, when I check the logs, this is the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'indexof'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename <module.js:338:15>
    at Function.Module._load <module.js:280:25>
    at Module.require <module.js:364:17>
    at require <module.js:380:17>
    at Object.<anonymous> </app/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/emitter/index.js:6:13>
    at Module._compile <module.js:456:26>
    at Object.Module._extensions..js <module.js:474:10>
    at Module.load <module.js:356:32>
    at Functin.Module._load <module.js:312:12>
    at Module.require <module.js:364:17>
```

So I figured out that indexof is a module that Socket.IO uses, and it is in my node_modules folder, but for some reason either it's not being pushed to heroku or it's just not being recognized. I reinstalled my modules 5-6 times and recreated the app but it's still giving me the same error. My package.json file has 3 dependencies: Express, Socket.IO and Jade

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Alright so after 2 hours I figured the problem out, multiple folders named "emitter" that contained the indexof module also had a gitignore file that made git ignore the module, no idea why that was even there, but deleting them fixed the problem

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Then I used `git add -A --force` it solved it.

Comment: SAME HERE. Why the hell did this happened

Comment: EXACTLY THE SAME HERE ;-)  you saved me a lots of time

Comment: Faulty .gitignore: `node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-adapter/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/emitter/.gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to add a few modules to dependencies, as they were only under devdependecies and were not built on production

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem , please read it carefully

> These are solutions to socket.io related problems

> I hope i will work

1. Ports in your (index.js or server.js) & (index.html and your client.js) port must be different. (refer below code)

> =============your index.js file ======================

> (port here is 8000)

```
const express = require("express")
var app = express();
const http = require('http')
var server = http.createServer(app);
  
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000
server.listen(port,()=>
{
    console.log("Listening at port => "+port)
});
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
    }
});

const cors = require("cors")
app.use(cors())
```

> =============your client.js file ======================

> port here is 8080

```
const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8080/')
```

> =============your index.html file ======================

> port here is 8080

```
 <script defer src="https://localhost:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"> 
 </script>
```

> Remember your "server.js or index.js" port should be different from "client.js" port (Rememeber this is important)

> (index.html and your client.js) port must be same

2. You should always use 'http' while working with socket.io (refer above code)
3. U may not included cors as it allows u to have more resourses , without cors heroku prevent some dependencies to not install in heroku (refer above code)
4. Try replacing "io" to "io.connect"

   const socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8080/')
5. Must write  tag at the end in the HTML
6. U may forget to add this code which is must in "socket.io"

It is required in your html file

7. delete "node_modules" and "package-lock.json"
   and write "npm i" in cmd
8. This should be in package.json 's scripts

   "start":"node index.js",

I am not talking about nodemon , use simple node over here

9. May be version is creating a problem , u can avoid it by copying all "devDependencies" to "dependencies" in "package.json" and put "*" in version like this

   "dependencies": {

   "cors": "*",

   "express": "*",

   "nodemon": "*",

   "socket.io": "*"

   },

   "devDependencies": {}