# Nodejs and socket.io in Openshift

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openshift

I'm doing this simple test on my nodejs app in Openshift. The code below was running fine and I was able to see index.html, until I added the line `var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);`. Now I'm getting the 503 - Service Temporarily Unavailable. I have socket.io installed in the `app-root/repo/node_modules` folder, and I've also included it to dependencies in package.json. What could be wrong?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
var io = require('socket.io').listen(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});

http.listen(server_port, server_ip_address);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works OK on my machine. Double check the dependencies, and above all the logs:

```
ssh to your gear
less app-root/logs/nodejs.log
```

Comment: In the dependencies I have:
  `"dependencies": {
    "express": "~3.4.4",
    "socket.io": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "bundleDependencies": [],
  "private": true,
  "main": "server.js"`

Comment: **Logs are:**
   `at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/[MY ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/emitter/index.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^`

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'indexof'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/[MY ID]/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/node_modules/emitter/index.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)`

Comment: `at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^`

Comment: Must be something local/config related. Here's something that sounds similar save Heroku involved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987571/node-js-app-works-locally-but-heroku-says-missing-module

Comment: You might also try: `npm install indexof` Or try to find it on the server: `find . -name package.json | grep indexof` (from the home dir)

Comment: That's it! It worked now, thank you! The solution was this simple: `git add -A --force`