# Heroku: Error: Cannot find module 'indexof'

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, socket.io

I have a node.js application that uses `socket.io` and `express`. When I deploy the application I get the error `Cannot find module 'indexof'`. I read about the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987571/node-js-app-works-locally-but-heroku-says-missing-module) but the thing is that I don't check-in my `node_modules` folder to heroku so not really sure how I can fix it. Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe add 'indexof' as a dependency in your package.json

Comment: @laggingreflex Yes that solved the issue. Appearently there is an indexof module (https://www.npmjs.org/package/indexof) which (may) cause errors on heroku.